# How to dynamically change the color of a v-icon from javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue page with three icons as below. I wanted to change the color of the icons when a condition is fulfilled in the code. I created a `computed` property and trying to access it in the local method of `initialize()`. But, this is neither changing the color nor throwing an error.

```
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-row no-gutters class="mt-3 pt-15" align="center" justify="center">
      <v-col class="mt-3" align="right">
        <v-icon :color="calibrate1.color">fas fa-circle</v-icon>
      </v-col>
      <v-col class="mt-3" align="center">
        <v-icon :color="calibrate2.color">fas fa-circle</v-icon>
      </v-col>
      <v-col class="mt-3" align="left">
        <v-icon :color="calibrate3.color">fas fa-circle</v-icon>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-card>
</template>


<script>
import { firebase, db, auth } from "@/firebase.js";

export default {
  name: "calibration",

  props: {
    lang: {
      type: String,
      default: "en-US",
    },
    isListening: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  },

  data: () => ({
    recognizing: false,
    keyWords: ["START", "BOLD", "STOP"],
    keyWordCount: 0,
    oldKeyWord: "",
    newKeyword: "",
    currentIteration: 0,
    calibrate1: {
      color: "default",
    },
    calibrate2: {
      color: "default",
    },
    calibrate3: {
      color: "default",
    },
  }),

  computed: {
    changeColor() {
      console.log("Iteration is: " + this.currentIteration);
      switch (this.currentIteration) {
        case 1:
          this.calibrate1.color = "light-green accent-4";
          break;
        case 2:
          this.calibrate2.color = "light-green accent-4";
          break;
        case 3:
          this.calibrate3.color = "light-green accent-4";
          break;
        default:
          this.calibrate1.color = "grey lighten-1";
          this.calibrate2.color = "grey lighten-14";
          this.calibrate3.color = "grey lighten-1";
      }
    },
  },

  methods: {
    initialize() {
      if (!("webkitSpeechRecognition" in window)) {
        upgrade();
      } else {
        const aux = this;
        console.log(this);
        this.recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
        this.recognition.continuous = true;
        this.recognition.interimResults = false;
        this.recognition.maxAlternatives = 3;
        this.newKeyword = this.keyWords[this.keyWordCount];

        this.recognition.onresult = function (event) {
          var current = event.resultIndex;
          var transcript = event.results[current][0].transcript;
          var alternatives = Array.from(event.results[current]);

          if (aux.oldKeyWord === aux.newKeyword && aux.currentIteration < 4) {
            aux.currentIteration = aux.currentIteration + 1;
            aux.changeColor; //Here I am trying to change the color
          } else if (aux.oldKeyWord !== aux.newKeyword) {
            aux.currentIteration = 1;
            aux.changeColor; //Here I am trying to change the color
          }
        };
      }
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    this.initialize();
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    this.recognition.stop();
  },
};
</script>
```

Looking forward to any help on this!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to bind the property with the `:`, so it doesn't eval the value, it's considered as string.

`<v-icon :color="calibrate3.color">fas fa-circle</v-icon>`

Comment: Thanks, I added it, but is still not working!